# Is there a program that can adjust display brightness according to battery percentage?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, kubuntu, power-management, brightness

When i work in Kubuntu, KDE power management has a section that lets you automatically adjust display brightness according to battery percentage.

I want to know if there is a tool like that in Ubuntu 12.04?

thanks.

Comment: Doesn't anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is not there anyway to do this?

Comment: I'm working on this and I'll post the solution in a few hours.

Comment: posted the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a script that checks the remaining battery every minute and adjusts the brightness accordingly. However, once the battery is below 30%, it sets the brightness to 0.

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do
    chargingState=$(grep "charging state:" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state | awk '{print $3}')
    batteryFull=$(grep "design capacity:" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info | awk '{print $3}')
    batteryRemaining=$(grep "remaining capacity:" /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state | awk '{print $3}')

    batteryPercentage=$((batteryRemaining * 100/batteryFull))

    if [ $chargingState == "discharging" ] 
    then
        if ((batteryPercentage > 30))
        then
            xbacklight -set $batteryPercentage
        else
            xbacklight -set 0
        fi
    fi

    sleep 60
done
```

- Copy this text to some file, say `batteryBrightness.sh`
- Make your script executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

- Open Startup Applications, from the cog menu present at the upper right corner.

[image: Cog menu]

- Click on *Add*.

[image: Startup Applications Dialog]

- Fill in all the details and click *Add*.

[image: Add Startup Application Preferences]

- Logout and login back to check.

**Note**:

- Change the name of the script to whatever you have named it, wherever required.
- You'd need the `xbacklight` package installed, if you don't have it installed, install it by running the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Comment: How can i change this script so that decrease brightness when my laptop is on battery too?

Comment: It changes according to the remaining battery percentage. It doesn't matter whether you're battery is charging or discharging.

Comment: It is important to me because i do not want i change brightness when i am on AC power, battery percentage is not important for me.

Comment: I'll modify it. Wait a minute.

Comment: added the changes.

Comment: If you wish, I can make a GUI version. But that might or might not happen.

Comment: Is there a way so that do not use while, something like register event?

Comment: Even if you use something like that, you would have to continuously check for the event. So, using it is inevitable.